# Solution of a differential equation?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Please, could someone help me to solve the differential equation$$u''(s)+\rho(s)\cdot [u'(s)]^2=0$$
for any arbitrary function $\rho$. We assume that the solution is a function of $\rho,u(0),u'^(0)$
My trial: I put $z=u'(s)$, then
$$\frac{dz}{ds}=-\rho z^2
\\ \frac{-1}{z}+\frac{1}{u'(0)}=-\int_0^s \rho ds
\\ \frac{1}{z}=\sigma(s)+c
\\ u(s)=\int_0^s\frac{1}{\sigma(s)+c}ds+u(0)$$
Where $\sigma(s)=\int_0^s \rho ds$
Now, the main point is to find the conditions on $\rho$ or else that grantee the existence of a non-trivial solution $u$ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way is to assume $u'(s)=y(s)$ which implies $u''(s)=y'(s)$. Indeed, $$u''(s)+\rho(s)u'(s)=0\to y'(s)+\rho(s)y(s)=0$$ which is a separable one.

Comment: I am so sorry, I edited it

Answer (score 2):

Try letting $y(s) = u'(s)$ and $y'(s) = u''(s)$.

Comment: I did then what

Comment: Solve it like you would any other linear first order equation. Integrating factor in general. This particular equation is separable.

Comment: I am so sorry, I edited it

Comment: Not a problem. You lost linear but it is still separable. If you don't have a specific function for $\rho$, then your final answer will have to contain an integral.

Comment: I wand to describe or get all properties of $u$ in terms of $\rho$

Comment: Don't forget you still have to solve for $u$ by replacing $z$ with $u'$ and integrating again.

Comment: I have updated this version